# What is the best powershell script to restore an SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

To restore an SQL Server 2008 database, I would lile to be able to just do something like this in powershell:

./restore.ps1 DatabaseName.bak

Then the powershell script would by convention restore it to a database with name "DatabaseName".  It would disconnect any user connected to this database so that it can restore the DB.  It would store the mdf and ldf in the default location.

This would mainly be while developing on my personal machine.  Just a quick way to restore a DB.

Anyone has such a script?

Thanks

Comment: If you're familiar with ADO.NET it isn't hard to create some wrappers around SqlConnection/SqlComment to set up parameters from a hash and then call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a script and posted it on [PoshCode](http://poshcode.org) which should meet your requirements. The script uses the [SQLPSX](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com) sqlserver module. Note I had to add a restore file list only option to the invoke-sqlrestore function, so you'll need to grab the module from source code section rather than download section. This will be added to a future release of SQLPSX:

Module:
http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/58378#564810

Script:
http://poshcode.org/2530

Answer (score 0):

Please refer **PowerShell script to backup a database and restore on other server**
http://bi-bigdata.com/2012/12/16/power-shell-script-to-backup-a-database-and-restore-on-other-server/

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using custom script created by following [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/backup-and-restore-sql-server-with-the-sql-server-2012-powershell-cmdlets/). The best part is that it does not use any third party tools or script, it only need couple of Microsoft modules installed to gain access to a whole slew of new PowerShell CMDlets. You can follow [this post](http://www.maxtblog.com/2012/09/create-powershell-smo-scripts-without-installing-sql-server/) to install them on your or any other management machine and use it to connect to any MSSQL since 2000 to manage it remotely with a single script.

The commands are multiple and give you easy access to every option, parameter and action of the SQL server. You can list them with `Get-Command -Module SQLPS` once you load the module.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245198.aspx) you can find more info about it.